# How create a new input field row by clicking a button reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs, button

I am building an ecommerce app and I want to collect the users different phone numbers and address.

I want to create a new field where the user types new phone number and address

I tried using state to accomplish the task but I am geting error

TypeError: contactInfo.phoneInputs is undefined

```
const RegisterModal = ({openRegisterModal, setOpenRegisterModal}) => {
    const [contactInfo, setContactInfo] = useState({
        phoneInputValue : {},
        phoneInputs: [],
        addressInputValue : {},
        addressInputs: [],
    })
    console.log(contactInfo)
    const addContact = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const contactsphoneInfo = "phoneNumber";
        const contactsAddressInfo = "address";
        let phoneInputBox = 
        <Input name={contactsphoneInfo} star="false" label="PhoneNumber" type="text" className="col-md-6" />

        let addressInputBox = 
        <Input name={contactsAddressInfo} star="false" label="address" type="text" className="col-md-6" />
        setContactInfo(contactInfo.phoneInputs.push({phoneInputBox}))
        console.log(contactInfo)
    }

return (
        <div>
          {
             contactInfo.phoneInputs.map(input => input)
           }
           button onClick={addContact}>Add</button>
</div>
```

)
}

export default RegisterModal

How do I fix this error

link to codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-morse-s6zn0

Answer (score 1):

your setstate is a bit fishy, I believe

```
setContactInfo({...contactInfo, phoneInputs: [...contactInfo.phoneInputs,phoneInputBox ]});
```

This should work . but i recommend you try for more clean code .
and console.log(contactInfo)  before render if you check itll be undefined if you want to check the inital value still use useEffect then log it .